# inserting data into multiple tables using procedure in oracle

Tags: triggers, procedure, sql-loader

I have 4 Tables

Customer(cust_id (PK), cust_phone, name)

Order((order_id,cust_id) (PK), order_date, order_amt)

Order_line((order_id,Product_id)(PK), qty)

Product(product_id, Product_name, product_price)

The order table has a composite key saying an order only exists with a customer.

The Order_line table has a composite key as it is a bridge table between product and order table. the order_amt is a calculated column, its the total order value.

The question is how do i insert data into the order table and the Order_line table? using procedure, triggers or a temp table or any other way? I am really stuck at this. Help!!

Do I need to make any changes in the model?

Comment: I will write the procedures and triggers and functions myself. 

I just want to know how to go about it.